# PHP preg_replace: find string part not starting with an exclamation point

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am working on some very messy Excel sheets, and trying to use PHP to find clues..

I have a MySQL database with all formulas from an excel document, and as usual, the cellnames from the current sheet do not have a "sheetname!" in front of it. To make it searchable (and find dead-routes in the formulas) I like to replace all formulas in the database with their sheetname as prefix.

Example:

```
=+(sheet_factory_costs!A17/sheet_employees!D23)+T12+W12
```

The database contains the name of the current sheet, and I like to change the formula above with that sheetname (let's call it "sheet_turnover").

```
=+(sheet_factory_costs!A17 / sheet_employees!D23)+sheet_turnover!T12+sheet_turnover!W12
```

I try this in PHP with preg_replace, and I think I need the following rules:

1. Find one or two letters, directly followed by a number. This is always a cell-adress within formulas.
2. When there is a ! on the position before, there is already a sheetname. So I am only looking for the letters and numbers NOT starting with an exclamation point.

The problem seems to be that the ! is also a special sign within patterns. Even if I try to escape it, it does not work:

```
$newformula = 
preg_replace('/(?<\!)[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]/', 
'lala', 
$oldformula);
```

(lala is my temporary marker to see if it is selecting the right cell-adresses)

(and yes, the lala is only places over the first number, but that's no issue right now)

(and yes, all Excel $..$.. (permanent) markers have already been replaced. No need to build that in the formula)

Comment: You need to double the backslash as it has an escaping meaning in string literals, which "eat" them.

Comment: Actually, `(?<\!)` is an invalid regex construct in PCRE, if you try it, you will get a warning about an incomplete group structure. It is not about how many escaping backslashes one needs here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your negative lookbehind is corrupt, you need to define it as `(?<!!)`. However, you also need to use either a word boundary before it, or a `(?<![A-Z])` lookbehind to make sure you have no other letters before the `[A-Z]{1,2}`.

So, you may use

```
'~\b(?<!!)[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KEDDZT/2). Replace with `sheet_turnover!$0` where `$0` is the whole match value.

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary (it is necessary, or `name!AA11` would still get matched)
- `(?<!!)` - no `!` immediately to the left of the current location
- `[A-Z]{1,2}`  - 1 or 2 letters
- `[0-9]` - a digit.

Another approach is match and skip "wrong" contexts and then match and keep the "right" ones:

```
'~\w+![A-Z]{1,2}[0-9](*SKIP)(*F)|\b[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]~'
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KEDDZT/3).

Here, `\w+![A-Z]{1,2}[0-9](*SKIP)(*F)|` part matches 1 or more word chars, then 1 or 2 uppercase ASCII letters and then a digit, and `(*SKIP)(*F)` will omit the match and will make the engine proceed looking for matches after the end of the previous match.

Comment: That doubled exclamation mark did the trick. I do not understand why I have to do it that way, but it works fine.

There are no differences in the results with or without the /b. Without the /b it does not affect the word before (the sheetname):

old :=+D16+(P25/(O25*(Entry_machines!C12)))
new: =+lala6+(lala5/(lala5*(Entry_machines!C12)))

Comment: @TwomuchTime I'd rather you treated it as a `!` inside `(?<!...)` (negative lookbehind) construct. Then, it becomes quite clear.

Comment: @TwomuchTime If there are two letters in the column name, `\b` will make a difference. Try against `+D16+(P25/(O25*(Entry_machines!CC12)))`